# Goodness-of-fit test applied to tuples in sequences/samples, instead of raw data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, goodness-of-fit

**High level problem:**

I have two sequences of data. The first one is the reference, the truth, the second is one which contains missed values (due to measurement errors). I want a test which can determine if the second *corrupted* sequence arose from the same distribution as my first clean sequence. I note e.g. that Watson’s U2 statistic was developed for distributions
which are cyclic (with ordering to the support but no natural starting point). Hence I am wondering if there is something similar for the monotonic sequences with which i am dealing.

Caveats:

I am dealing with sequential data, which has a particular structure, an example:

$x = \{a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c\}$, then $|x| = N = 12$ and the alphabet is $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$

The structure is thus: each symbol in $\Sigma$ is repeated $r=4$ times. In the corrupted $x$ let's call it $x'$, $r$ is not uniform because of measurement errors.

$x' = \{a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c\}$.

Because I have lots of corrupted sequences, and only one reference, I need some test to ascertain if the corrupted sequences arose from the reference distribution.

---

Toy example: I want to measure the goodness-of-fit between these two samples. Now there are a few problems, which I would like clarification on (specifically since this is ordered data).

The distribution of each all my sequences is uniform over their alphabet (a simple histogram of $x$ will show this to be true). But I am interested in preserving the sequential information in my samples ($x$ and $x'$). Consequently, I was wondering if it makes sense to measure the GoF between the [$n-$tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) / sub-sequences present in both sequences, instead of on the raw values in each sequence directly.

The tuple information that matters for my application, are the identical ones. You'll notice that $x[0:4] = \{a,a,a,a\}$, if I am to measure the number of symbol-identical 2-tuples, 3-tuples and 4-tuples in this segment, I would get:

- $ \#tuple_2 = 1+1+1 =3$ (i.e. we're counting 2-tuples: $[a,a]$)
- $ \#tuple_3 =
     1+1 =2$ (i.e. we're counting 3-tuple: $[a,a,a]$)
- $ \#tuple_4 =
     1$ (i.e. we're counting 4-tuple: $[a,a,a,a]$)

I extend this approach to the whole sequence ($x$), where I am continuously looking for symbol-identical tuples up to the size of four. Hence all I have done is to count how many times sub-sequences which look like this $[j,j], [j,j,j], [j,j,j,j], j \in \{a,b,c\}$, appear in $x$ and $x'$.

$tuples_{x} = 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4$ (here a '2' indicates that e.g. $[a,a]$ was counted once).

I then do the same thing for $x'$.

My question is now then; does it make sense to compare the data on tuple lengths between $x$ and $x'$ to preserve some (any at all) of the sequential information in either sample.

**CLARIFICATIONS**

1. Where is the "fit" whose goodness you want to assess?

A: My null hypothesis is that $x'$ originates from the same distribution as $x$  (though I daresay I have misunderstood something here because they are sequential time-series, hence I suspect this methodology does not work here).

2. Exactly how does this "corruption" work?

A: Missed values in the measurement process for example, sensors breaking down is a very real possibility.

3. In what sense do you mean a distribution is "uniform"?

A: Just creating a histogram of the raw values in $x$ e.g. will crudely show a uniform distribution over $\{a,b,c\}$.

4. What do you mean by "n-tuple" when the samples clearly have different lengths?

A: I mean measure how many times e.g. the 2-tuple $[a,a]$ appears in both $x$ and $x'$ -- clearly because one is corrupted, the count will not be equal.

5. What exactly is a "tuple .. within a segment"?

A: Simply an ordered sub-sequence within the larger sequence. E.g. $[a,a,a]$ is a 3-tuple contained in $x$ because we can find that exact segment in $x$.

Comment: Some crucial elements of this question are vague and need more detailed explanation.  First, where is the "fit" whose goodness you want to assess?  Second, exactly how does this "corruption" work?  Third, in what sense do you mean a distribution is "uniform"?  Fourth, what do you mean by "$n$-tuple" when the samples clearly have *different* lengths? Fifth, what exactly is a "tuple .. within a segment"? Sixth, what is a "raw tuple length"? (Your example is difficult to follow.)  As a rule, you would be better off telling us the problem you actually face rather than trying to pose it abstractly.

Comment: Rather spookily I was just reading your response to another question :) Allow me to clarify your very good questions in my query.